# Node.js winston logger; How to start from a newline when insert log into log file?

Tags: node.js, newline, winston

I'm making a Node.js app and I am using Winston for most of my logging purposes.
But I find all records in log file in one line, I want to change line for every log record, any way can do this?
My code;

```
var winston = require("winston"); var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
transports: [
new(winston.transports.Console)(),
new(winston.transports.File)({filename: './log/logFile.log', handleExceptions: true, json:true})
]
```

})

Just like that:

```
{"level":"info","message":"test","timestamp":"2012-12-05T07:12:23.774Z"}

{"level":"info","message":"test","timestamp":"2012-12-05T07:15:16.780Z"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not winston issue. Winston uses Unix style for new line (i.e. only one character xOA).

You just need stop using Windows Notepad, and start using other text editor (like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/)) or IDE like [Enide Studio](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/).

BTW newer winston has options for time format.