# Winston logger not being printed on new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

This is my winston logger -

```
var winston = require('winston')

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      // log which takes care of all the MAS scoring - node clusters and servers
      filename: './test.log',
      level: 'info',
      json: true,
      eol: 'rn'
    })
  ]
})
```

And when I run the actual logger:

```
logger.info('hi', 'it meeeeee')
logger.info('hi', 'it youuuuuu')
```

It prints out like this in the test.log file -

```
{"level":"info","message":"hi it meeeeee","timestamp":"2016-08-18T08:42:01.768Z"}rn{"level":"info","message":"hi it youuuuuu","timestamp":"2016-08-18T08:42:01.770Z"}rn
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
{"level":"info","message":"hi it meeeeee","timestamp":"2016-08-18T08:42:01.768Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"hi it youuuuuu","timestamp":"2016-08-18T08:42:01.770Z"}
```

How is this possible? I have read this question [Node.js winston logger; How to start from a newline when insert log into log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718264/node-js-winston-logger-how-to-start-from-a-newline-when-insert-log-into-log-fil) - however it does not solve the issue in my case.

I.e. if I open in Notepad ++, command line or Sublime text I still get the same issue.

Comment: It is true what Ramesh said. Winston allows you to add any STRING! to "end of the line" (which is considered at each log input). You added two letters "rn" at the end, therefore it does exactly what is supposed to. The "r" and "\r" are different characters. PS: Do you need to change eol at all? Most modern programs can open and edit both - windows and linux styles documents... Which means I would suggest to just delete the line with `eol` (or use Ramesh solution, if you insist on windows-like end of line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `eol: \r\n`

Look [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol)